# Video not working in IE11 without console

Tags: internet-explorer, console, html5-video

Good day, everybody!

I've got a bit of a problem with IE. I have a background video on my website in normal browsers it works fine, but IE doesn't play it untill i open console and reload the page, than it works fine. Have anyone seen such stuff before? May be some advises in this situation. I will attach some code if needed. 
Thank you in advance.

UPD Here is the [link](http://bcpp2.monamiadv.com.ua/catalog.html) to check. Just open it in IE and reload page with console opened.

Comment: It sounds like there is a `console.log` somewhere in the code. Some browsers (IE, maybe others too) throw an error if you try to use the log when log window is not activated.

Comment: @Guffa No, I don't have logs in any scripts used on this page.

Comment: When I test it in IE 11, the video works fine without the console.

Comment: @Guffa Could you please compare it's work in IE with it's work in other browser like chrome or safari? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks the same as in Firefox.

Comment: @Guffa Thank you, appreciate that.